# Why docker-compose do not use port binding as expected?

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I'm using this docker-compose config for running a classic nodejs app + mysql + redis:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    build: 
      context: ./app/
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - elasticsearch
    links:
      - db
      - redis
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:${APP_PORT}:${APP_PORT}"
    environment:
      - "PORT=${APP_PORT}"
      - "MYSQL_PORT=${MYSQL_PORT}"
      - "REDIS_PORT=${REDIS_PORT}"

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: "redis:3-alpine"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:${REDIS_PORT}:6379"

  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mariadb:10.0.30
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "${MYSQL_DATA_LOCATION}/data:/var/lib/mysql:delegated"
      - "${MYSQL_DATA_LOCATION}/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf:ro"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      - "MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
```

I'm also using a .env file containing the following values:

```
APP_PORT=5000
MYSQL_PORT=3306
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

And I start the application with

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Everything runs fine this way. I can change the mysql port without error, but if I change the redis port to something else than the original port, I have the following error in the app, when I use this config:

```
redis.createClient({host: 'redis', port: process.env.REDIS_PORT });
```

I get the following message:

```
Error: Redis connection to redis:5555 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.3:5555
```

Whereas the connection between the db and the app works correctly :s

In docker ps I can see that the machine started with the expected config:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                NAMES
9c594c6d98b8        nginx:mainline-alpine          "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   33 seconds ago      Up 39 seconds       0.0.0.0:2000->80/tcp                                 webproxy
62d1f917d7ff        app                            "npm run docker-debug"   36 seconds ago      Up 42 seconds       127.0.0.1:5000->5000/tcp, 127.0.0.1:9222->9222/tcp   app
7c982d543a7d        mariadb:10.0.30                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   39 seconds ago      Up 45 seconds       127.0.0.1:4000->3306/tcp                             db
9dd13967b37d        redis:3                        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   39 seconds ago      Up 44 seconds       127.0.0.1:5555->6379/tcp                             redis
```

I can see here that the db is mapped from 4000 to 3306, which works, but the redis mapping from 5555 to 6379 is ignored. And if I manually change the port in the app connection to port 6379, it does work...

Is there something missing in my configuration ?

Comment: Are you sure image “redis:3-alpine” is using 6379?  Where does the 5555 mentioned in the error msg come from?  Look at your docket-compose.yml file again.

Comment: @zipzit yes, I can see it with the docker inspect redis command

Answer (score 1):

the redis is running **inside the container** on port 6379 period (if you dont change the port in its config). On your host you map port 5555 to redis container 6379. All services in docker-compose are visible to each other and you dont even need to EXPOSE those ports to host. In your app settings if you access the redis by `redis://redis:6379` will work or with the exposed port `redis://HOST_IP:5555` will work too

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed from app I can use port 6379, but why can't I use port 5555? I get a connection error when I connect the app client to this port, I don't have this problem on the db container

Comment: because the container `redis` is not aware of any port 5555. This port exist only on the host.

Comment: Sory if I was not clear, but my question is: why the app cannot connect to redis using redis://redis:5555, whereas I can connect to db using mysql://db:4000 ?